# How to Transform a List of Integers to a Matrix of True and False in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In this exercise I should write a function which receives a list of integers as argument and gives a matrix or list of lists. The point in making the matrix is that the integers represent the number of `True`s in each *column* of the matrix. For example

```
[2,4,1]
```

must be translated to:

[image]

which in the system is represented as a list of lists:

```
[ [0,1,0], [0,1,0], [1,1,0], [1,1,1] ]
```

As it's not easy to manipulate matrices (list of lists) by columns I used a trick and rotate the matrix by 90 degree to the left using `transpose` which makes the matrix looks like below:

[image]

Then I developed the following algorithm to solve the problem:

1. Take the first element of the input list
2. Create a list of length `maximum xs` (the length of each list is equal to the maximum element in the list)
3. Put so many `True` in the list as the first element determines.
4. Fill in the the rest of the list with `False`
5. Do the same for all elements and rotate the matrix

I have tried to implement two solutions but each one has a problem which I cannot solve:

1. This one works for the first element just fine but I do not know how to apply it to all elements of the input list

   ```
   listToMatrix x = (replicate ((maximum x) - (head x)) False) ++ (replicate (head x) True)`
   ```
2. This works for all elements but can not keep the length of the inner list so the lists have different lengths.

   ```
   listToMatrix lst@(x:xs) = ((replicate ((maximum lst) - x) False) ++ (replicate x True)) : listToMatrix xs`
   ```

**Question 1**: How can I make these functions work with minimal changes?

**Question 2**: Are more elegant and compact solutions?

P.S. I used 1 and 0 in the matrices to make them more readable but they are in fact True and False

Comment: It is a sort of project. Why?

Comment: Well, at least it shows effort, unlike most SO homework questions. It does not simply ask "gimme code", but provides an attempt at a solution.

Comment: Transposition is a good technique at simplifying these sorts of generate-a-matrix questions, but in this case I think there exists a simple solution for the original non-transposed form. Perhaps this will help: there's a way to generate the matrix you want using a list comprehension nested inside another list comprehension (a.k.a. a map nested in another map). Another hint: precompute the maximum and store it around, so as not to pay that cost over and over again.

Comment: http://ideone.com/rYIXX3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the following approach, which is compatible with yours.

As you proposed, we use `transpose` at the end, since the transposed matrix looks easier to generate.

```
f :: [Int] -> [[Bool]]
f xs = transpose (...)
```

Then, each element of `xs` has to generate a new row. We can either use a list comprehension (done below), or alternatively use `map`.

```
f :: [Int] -> [[Bool]]
f xs = transpose [ row x | x <- xs ]
  where row :: Int -> [Bool]
        row x = ...
```

As you suggest, we also need `maximum` to generate each row, so we compute it once:

```
f :: [Int] -> [[Bool]]
f xs = transpose [ row x | x <- xs ]
  where m = maximum xs
        row :: Int -> [Bool]
        row x = ...   -- we know x and m, we need m-x Falses and x Trues
```

Now, you just need to adapt your code.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it:

```hs
toMatrix' :: [[Bool]] -> [Int] -> [[Bool]]
toMatrix' acc xs
    | or  bools = toMatrix' (bools : acc) (map pred xs)
    | otherwise = acc
    where bools = map (> 0) xs

toMatrix :: [Int] -> [[Bool]]
toMatrix = toMatrix' []
```

Simple and straightforward. No need to transpose.

Here's the visualization of my program. I'll use `0` and `1` for `False` and `True` respectively.

```hs
toMatrix [2,4,1] = toMatrix' []                                [ 2, 4, 1]
                 = toMatrix' [[1,1,1]]                         [ 1, 3, 0]
                 = toMatrix' [[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]                 [ 0, 2,-1]
                 = toMatrix' [[0,1,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]         [-1, 1,-2]
                 = toMatrix' [[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]] [-2, 0,-3]
                 = [[0,1,0],
                    [0,1,0],
                    [1,1,0],
                    [1,1,1]]
```

When we call `toMatrix' acc xs` we first compute `bools = map (> 0) xs`. If all the elements of `bools` are `False` then we're done. We simple return `acc`. Otherwise we add `bools` to the beginning of `acc` and subtract one from each element of `xs`. Rinse and repeat.

No need to keep track of the biggest element of `xs` and no need to transpose the matrix. Simple.

Comment: This is a nice answer, a summary of why you structured it the way you did would make it even nicer.

Comment: This generates the matrix upside down from the example in the OP's post. If instead of counting the individual elements of the source array down, you pass an additional countdown that starts at the maximum and eventually reaches 0, and fill each element with whether this countdown is smaller or equal to the source element, you get the right ordering.

Comment: @SebastianRedl No. It generates the matrix the right side up. I know it because I wrote the function and tested it. You should test it yourself.

Comment: Good addition.  +1 for completeness!